# Does the law of conservation of momentum also hold for position and acceleration?

Tags: classical-mechanics, conservation-laws

The following is the law of conservation of momentum (in terms of velocity):

$$m_1\mathbf{v_1} + m_2 \mathbf{v_2} = m_1 \mathbf{v_1}^\prime + m_2 \mathbf{v_2}^\prime.$$

Does the law of conservation of momentum also hold for position and acceleration? Since position and acceleration are the $0$th and $2nd$ derivatives (of position), respectively, I suspect that it does. If so, then, putting the law of conservation in terms of **position**, we get

$$m_1 \mathbf{r_1} + m_2 \mathbf{r_2} = m_1 \mathbf{r_1}^\prime + m_2 \mathbf{r_2}^\prime.$$

I would greatly appreciate it if someone would please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: What you have written doesn't say alot about convervation of linear momentum and it is only true if $v=v^{\prime}$.  You have written $(m_1+m_2)v = (m_1+m_2)v^{\prime}$.  Does this look like a demonstration of conservation of linear momentum?

Comment: I made some edits I believe reflect your intention. Please review

Comment: @Dale I seemed to have written it incorrectly. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conservation of position is not valid. Consider an isolated point particle of mass $m_1$ moving inertially at some non-zero velocity. For such a particle $m_1 \mathbf r_1 \ne m_1 \mathbf r_1’$ and since it is isolated $m_2=0$. So the proposed conservation equation does not hold.

In general it does not hold whenever the center of mass of the system is moving.

Comment: What about in the case of this problem https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/559023/141502 ? If you refer to that problem, you’ll see why I asked this question and be able to infer what I’m trying to do here. I didn’t want to add too many details to this question and make it unfocused, so I left out all of this stuff and just asked the question in a focused and isolated way.

Comment: Sorry, I saw that question earlier but didn’t have a good answer. But regardless of that question, the conservation of position isn’t valid.